# Get real time running processes in WPF checked listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Basically I'm having this code which is executed every 2s in a timer :

```
void GetAllPlayerWindows()
{
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("gamex");

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;

            if (p.MainWindowTitle != "Login")
            {
                Character player = new Character();
                player.Handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                player.Name = p.MainWindowTitle;
                lstPlayers.Items.Add(player);
            }
        }
}
```

This is the Character class:

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; } //MainWindowTitle
    public IntPtr Handle { get; set; } //MainWindowHandle
}
```

This is my WPF checked listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstPlayers" ItemsSource="{Binding playerList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I cannot figure out how to monitor the "gamex" processes and make it coordinate with the listbox. So that if a new process if spawned it creates an item, if it's deleted, it deletes it. As the `GetAllPlayerWindows()` is executed every 2s it keeps adding every process to the listbox and make duplicates. How to prevent that ?

What I want to achieve :

Having a listbox which always updates and gets the processes that are named "gamex", get theire mainwindowtitle and make sure it's not "Login". Then create a new Character instance and put process Handle & Window Title as Name in there. And put this Character instance in listbox. So that I could access it's items and get the name & handle.

Comment: As you keep the MainWindowHandle it is easy to loop over your list and only add an item if the MainWindowHandle isn't in the list. You can all do this inside `GetAllPlayerWindows`

Comment: This is actually my main problem. Could you provide an example ? I start with "for each process p in process" and then How would I say "if listbox doesnt contains Character who's Handle property != p.MainWindowHandle" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do a [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) on your lstPlayers. If it return null the process is not yet in the list, in which case you add it.

```
void GetAllPlayerWindows()
{
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("gamex");

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;

            if (p.MainWindowTitle != "Login")
            {
                // find if the handle already is in the list
                if (lstPlayers.Find(i => i.Handle == windowHandle) == null)
                { 
                   // it is not, add it 
                   Character player = new Character();
                   player.Handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                   player.Name = p.MainWindowTitle;
                   lstPlayers.Items.Add(player);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found my own answer:

```
void GetAllPlayerWindows()
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("gamex");

    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;

        if (p.MainWindowTitle != "Login" && !ContainsHandle(p))//<--Made a little function
        {
            Character player = new Character();
            player.Handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
            player.Name = p.MainWindowTitle;
            lstPlayers.Items.Add(player);
        }
    }
}

bool ContainsHandle(Process p)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < lstPlayers.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Character player = lstPlayers.Items[i] as Character;
            if (player.Handle == p.MainWindowHandle)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```